# RxJs conact operator with async pipe not working

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs, concatenation, pipe

I new to RxJs and practicing. I just used simplest of angular code rather than console.log for output.

**My copmonent code is:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, map, of, Subject, BehaviorSubject, AsyncSubject, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  obs1$ = of(1, 2, 3);
  obs2$ = of(4, 5, 6);
  obs3$ = of(7, 8, 9);

  concat$ = concat(this.obs1$, this.obs2$, this.obs3$);
}
```

**My template code is:**

```
<p *ngFor="let x of concat$ | async">
    {{x}}
</p>
```

The above code is giving me the following error:
**Cannot find a differ supporting object '9' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Screen shot attached.**

When I am subscribing and outputing in console it is giving result as expected: 1, 2, 3, till 9.

Am I missing something? Something I did not understand yet?

Please help me on this query.

Simply outputing

{{concat$ | async}}

is displaying 9 on the UI. The last emitted value.

When I am subscribing and outputing in console it is giving result as expected: 1, 2, 3, till 9.

Comment: The source of the issue is neither RxJS `concat` operator, nor the Angular `async` pipe. The issue from using Angular `*ngFor` directive to iterate over something that is not iterable. In simple, `*ngFor` needs an iterable (eg. an array). However the `of(1, 2, 3)` observables do NOT emit an array. It emits individual values as such. Simply replace the source observables to `of([1, 2, 3])` form, i.e. wrap the values in an array to see the difference. The output wouldn't be the expected 1...9, but it'd give you a good starting point to see the difference b/n `of(1, 2, 3)` and `of([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: Also since you mentioned you're starting with RxJS, here's one more tip: The observables `of(1, 2, 3)` and `from([1, 2, 3])` would emit the same output. Gives a good starting point to learn how `of` and `from` varies although both at first might seem to serve the same purpose. Additionally, `from()` function can be used to _convert_ Promises to Observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RxJs, `concat` isn't the same the `concat` you'd use on an array. Concat is to chain sequentially a list of observables. They'll still **emit one value at a time**.

Meaning that in your view, you wouldn't need an `ngFor`, as what you get isn't an array but rather a value at one point in time.

So when you do

```js
  obs1$ = of(1, 2, 3);
  obs2$ = of(4, 5, 6);
  obs3$ = of(7, 8, 9);

  concat$ = concat(this.obs1$, this.obs2$, this.obs3$);
```

You'll get one value at a time: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

So either you just display the current value... OR you want to display all the values. For this, you have 2 options:

You want to display all the values received at once, at the end once the observable is closed. In which case you can do exactly what [fuji as explained with toArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695754/2398593).

Otherwise, if you prefer to show accumulated values over time, essentially get:

- `[1]`
- `[1, 2]`
- `[1, 2, 3]`
  ...
- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

You can use `scan` to accumulate values over time but still emit intermediate values:

```
concat(this.obs1$, this.obs2$, this.obs3$).pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an array out of all observables emitted values, you can use [`toArray()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) operator

```
concatToArray$ = concat(this.obs1$, this.obs2$, this.obs3$).pipe(toArray);

// output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```